# How can I execute a JavaScript function to use a different stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I want to serve up a different stylesheet if my app is loaded within an iframe. What JavaScript event do I use to do this check, and how do I serve up the different stylesheet?

EDIT:

I tried wiring this to the body `onLoad` event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkFrame() {
        if (window.top!=window.self)
        {
            // In a Frame or IFrame
            document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/custom/embedded'>");
        }
        else
        {
            // Not in a frame
            document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/custom/standard'>");
        }
    }
</script>
```

but it displays a blank page only the stylesheet link in it.

Comment: Thanks everybody, +1s all around for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, in jQuery. I was overcomplicating it.

```
$(function() {

    if (window.top!=window.self) {
        // my css switcher
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into window.parent.  If it's not null, then you're inside a frame.  I don't think there is an "event" that fires.

Answer (score 1):

If window.parent is not == null, then you are in a frame.  You can also access information about the containing page this way.

You can wire up to the body onload event.

Answer (score 1):

I've used jQuery to do on-the-fly style sheet switching. I'm sure there's a pure JS equal. Assuming your `<head>....</head>` contains

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='styles.php?theme=default' />
```

then you can reload your CSS files (or the same CSS file with passed values) this way

```
 $('link').attr('href','styles.php?theme=' + newTheme);
```

Answer (score 1):

A List Apart has a pretty nice style switcher.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/